# Display daily tip, no database

Tags: random, asp-classic

I have approximately 100 tips that I need to display randomly on a site, different tip each day, and there is no access to a database. I have thought about putting the tips into array groups and associating each group with a day of the month, but that would not make the tips show up randomly. What is a relatively painless way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to display only one tip a day, and you can't store any state, you can do the following:

1. Sort the tips using some deterministic method.
2. Seed a random number generator with today's date.
3. Display the `i`<sup>th</sup> tip where `i = random.Next(numTips)`
4. Repeat this whole process (including reseeding the random number generator) each time.

If you also want to ensure each tip is displayed at least once before a tip is repeated:

1. Seed a random number generator with a constant value (*not* the current time, this is important).
2. Shuffle the elements with [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), using the not-so-random number generator you created.  Or use LINQ:

   ```
   tips.OrderBy(x => random.Next()).ToArray();
   ```
3. Display the `i`<sup>th</sup> tip mod `tips.Length` where `i` is the number of days since Epoch.

Answer (score 0):

Pick a random number between 1 and 100, display that tip.

If you can have the tips on disk, name them in files 1.tip through 100.tip, then when you pick your number, just read in and display that file.

If you have the tips in memory somehow (an array would be easiest), just display the tip pointed to by your random number, minus one (assuming you have zero-based array indexing).

Unless I'm missing something fundamental here, that's the basic gist.

Comment: I was thinking along those lines, however the tip needs to be displayed for one day, i.e. reloading the page **today** does not change the tip shown, only tomorrow, etc.

Answer (score 0):

in your tip display file have a function which checks the date in the session start section.  have the date checker calculate which day of the year it is - day 1, 2 3,...100.

select the tip file according to the annual day count.  if greater than 100 restart at 1.